# Что лучше использовать QtDesigner или QtCreator?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

Я видел, что в QtCreator возможностей больше чем в qt Designer. Но при этом там используют Pyside2

В чём разница между Pyside2 и Pyqt5??

Comment: Основное отличие -- это лицензии под которыми распространяются эти две обёртки над Qt. PyQt5 распространяется под GPL и коммерческой лицензией. PySide2 распространяется как Qt под GPL, LGPL и коммерческой лицензией.

Comment: @S.Nick Не очень вас понял. А в итоге что лучше? Можно ли на qtdesigner создавать анимированные объекты? например вот капает дождик с тучи, такое сделать можно?

Comment: Вы спросили: "В чём разница между Pyside2 и Pyqt5?", я вам ответил. Qt Designer -  средство создания форм https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Designer.  Qt Creator - кроссплатформенная свободная IDE для разработки на С, С++ и QML https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator.   Анимированные объекты не делаются в Qt_Designer, а пишутся в коде - ручками.

Comment: @S.Nick, теперь понял. А не могли бы вы подсказать где можно посмотреть, как делать анимированные объекты?

Comment: так полным полно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A217323+%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86

Comment: @S.Nick ох, как-то очень сложно